# gridview->boundfield and code behind (Linq)

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, gridview

Can i define in asp a boundField...:

```
        <asp:GridView ID="m_LinqDbGridView" runat="server">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="sVorname" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

...and use this code behind:

```
  DataClassesDataContext testDb = new DataClassesDataContext();

  var abfrage = from tblGeburtstag in testDb.tblGeburtstag
                select tblGeburtstag.sVorname;

  m_LinqDbGridView.DataSource = abfrage;
  m_LinqDbGridView.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
  m_LinqDbGridView.DataBind();
```

i get error message:

{"Feld oder Eigenschaft mit dem Namen sVorname wurde nicht in der ausgewählten Datenquelle gefunden."}
->>> field or property with the name sVorname not found in the selected datasource.
thanks.

Comment: It sounds like `sVorname` was not found in your data source. Can you confirm that isn't the case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

linq code was wrong! solution:

```
      var abfrage = (from geb in testDb.tblGeburtstag
                 select new {
                    geb.sVorname
                 });
```